# Tomcat seems to reference an older version of a dependency (spring-web)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ with the IvyIdea plugin. I added spring as dependency, rev 4.3.16 (the one my team uses).
After successfully building the project (which is a rest api), I tried to deploy it as an exploded war using tomcat 8.5.12 (again, the one my team is using).

When the deployment is running I get this exception:
`NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager.getStrategy(Ljava/lang/Class;)`

Reading the official documentation, I can see that the `getStrategy` method was introduced on Spring 4.3 so not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried cleaning the Ivy cache but it didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "to deploy it as an exploded war", why not as a regular war? how the war is built?

Comment: Solved. It was a bug by the looks of it. Thanks